# Week Start date from a Date MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a field with dates, I will like to run a query that updates another field with the Week Start Date (Sunday). How can I do that ?
I am using MS Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a combination of the DateAdd() and Weekday() functions, as in:

```sql
UPDATE theTable SET weekStartDate = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(theDate) + 1, theDate)
```